# Using object file to call winapi functions

Tags: c++, file, object, compilation

I am using an object file from a `.cpp` file, that I link to a `.c` test program.

In the object file are functions that use the Win32 API, for example:

```
std::string gettheVolumeSize()
{
    //vector for the volume size
    std::stringstream vs;
    std::string myvolumesize;
    std::vector<std::string> volumeSize;
    if (!GetSystemDirectory(infoBuf, INFO_BUFFER_SIZE))
    {

    }
    else {
    //  _tprintf(TEXT("\nSystem Directory:   %s"), infoBuf);
    }
    char* variable;

    variable = getenv("SystemDrive");
    std::string use = std::string(variable);    

    __int64 total, free;
    USES_CONVERSION_EX;
    std::string path;

    //create path for the diskspace request
    path = use + "\\\\";

    printf("%s", path);
    LPWSTR mypath = A2W_EX(path.c_str(), text.length());
    LPCTSTR tt = reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(mypath);
    printf("%ls", tt);
    //fill vector with volumeSize
    GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(tt, NULL, (PULARGE_INTEGER)&total, (PULARGE_INTEGER)&free);  
    printf("%llu", total);
    std::stringstream testit;
    const char* totalSize;
    int roundsize;
    roundsize = round((((__int64)total) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)));

    vs << round((((__int64)total) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)));
    vs >> myvolumesize;

    return myvolumesize;
}
```

My problem is that now I have different `volumeSizes` when I call the function in my `.c` test program.

Linking options:

> cl /c /nologo /c /MT /I. testprogramm.c testprogramm.c
>
> LINK /nologo
>   /OPT:NOREF /NXCOMPAT /DynamicBase /out:test.exe testprogramm.obj
>   SHA1.obj it4ecidtest.obj LIBCPMT.LIB libcmt.lib libvcruntime.lib
>   oldnames.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib netapi32.lib gdi32.lib
>   comdlg32.lib  comctl32.lib wsock32.lib shell32.lib Rpcrt4.lib
>   oleaut32.lib Ole32.lib Wbemuuid.lib wintrust.lib crypt32.lib
>   Ws2_32.lib iphlpapi.lib Psapi.lib advapi32.lib Shlwapi.lib
>   dhcpcsvc.lib userenv.lib atls.lib msvcrtd.lib vcruntimed.lib
>   netapi32.lib Advapi32.lib IPHLPAPI.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib
>   winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib
>   oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

Edited:

The output is `1996888586` when I call the function in the object file, and total = 512003928064 in the normal `.cpp` test program.

I just use `printf` to check the values, I dont return the output to my `.c` file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "it4ecid.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    char* cstring = getCompositeID();   
    printf("%s", cstring);
    return 0;
}
```

To make it clear: I create an object file from my `.cpp` file and call its `getCompositeID()` function in the test program, which is written in C.

`getCompositeID` is a function in the `.cpp` file, which is right now just calling the `gettheVolumeSize()` function.

Comment: _different volumeSizes_: different from what? Please elaborate your question. What output do you get? What output do you expect?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And how will you call a C++ function returning a C++ object, from a C source file? Maybe that's the problem you have?

Comment: Edited: output of function: total value

Comment: You forgot to show us the C code.

Comment: Edited: .c file code

Comment: In your C++ code you have the `gettheVolumeSize` function but in your C code you call the `getCompositeID` function. Please clarify... this is totally unclear.

Comment: I am sorry for this, I edited again

Comment: @objectfiles don't describe your code but show it. And you should consider to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @objectfiles sigh... pleeeease show `getCompositeID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `getCompositeID()` just calls `gettheVolumeSize()`, but the former returns a `char*` while the latter returns a `std::string`. If you are doing something like this:

```
char* getCompositeID() {
    return gettheVolumeSize().c_str();
}
```

Then your `main()` code is passing an invalid pointer to `printf()`, which is undefined behavior.

To ensure the string memory persists beyond the function call, you would have to save the `std::string` to a local-static or global variable, eg:

```
char* getCompositeID() {
    static std::string size;
    size = gettheVolumeSize();
    return size.c_str();
}
```

Or:

```
static std::string volumeSize;

char* getCompositeID() {
    volumeSize = gettheVolumeSize();
    return volumeSize.c_str();
}
```

But neither approach is thread safe.  If you need thread safety, you could use Thread-Local Storage, eg:

```
__thread std::string volumeSize;

char* getCompositeID() {
    volumeSize = gettheVolumeSize();
return volumeSize.c_str();
}
```

Otherwise, have `getCompositeID()` dynamically allocate a `char[]` copy of the `std::string` data and have `main()` free it:

```
char* getCompositeID() {
    std::string size = gettheVolumeSize();
    char *ret = (char*) malloc(size.length()+1);
    if (ret) strcpy(ret, size.c_str());
    return ret;
}
```

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    char* cstring = getCompositeID();
    printf("%s", cstring);
    free(cstring);
    return 0;
}
```

In any case, your `gettheVolumeSize()` is more complicated then it needs to be, and it has errors in it. It can be greatly simplified to something more like this:

```
std::string gettheVolumeSize() {
    std::string path;

    //create path for the diskspace request
    /*
    char    sysDir[MAX_PATH] = {};
    if (!GetSystemDirectoryA(sysDir, MAX_PATH)) return "";
    printf("%s", sysDir);
    path = sysDir;  
    */
    char *variable = getenv("SystemDrive");
    if (!variable) return "";
    path = std::string(variable) + "\\";
    printf("%s", path.c_str());

    //get volume size
    ULARGE_INTEGER totalSize;
    if (!GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(path.c_str(), NULL, &totalSize, NULL)) return "";
    printf("%llu", totalSize.QuadPart);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << round(double(totalSize.QuadPart) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024));
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: if (!GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(path.c_str(), NULL, &total, &free)) return "" says incompatible types long long and Pularge_Integer

Comment: @objectfiles did you change your `total` and `free` variables from `__int64` to `ULARGE_INTEGER`? If so, and you are still getting the error, then you have a conflicting definition of `ULARGE_INTEGER` somewhere. This code needs the [one from the Win32 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742.aspx).